# Compute $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\frac{981}{n+5}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left (\frac{i^2}{n^2} \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

Compute the given limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{981}{n+5}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left (\frac{i^2}{n^2} \right)
$$
The sum is:

Can someone please show me the steps to complete this problem?  The answer I arrived at was 0 but the homework program is telling me that it's wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider upvoting or accepting an answer (by clicking the $\checkmark$) if an answer helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly calculate the sum$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i^2}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\frac{\not n^2}{\not{n^2}}\frac{(1+\frac1n)(2n+1)}{6}$$ Therefore $$\begin{align*}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{981}{n+5}\frac{(1+\frac1n)(2n+1)}{6}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\not n}{\not n}\frac{981(1+\frac1n)(2+\frac1n)}{6(1+\frac5n)}\overset{\frac1n\to 0}=\\\\&=\frac{981(1+0)\cdot(2+0)}{6(1+0)}=\frac{981\cdot2}{6}=\frac{981}{3}=327\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you.  Can you please outline the formula behind doing this type of problem with the limit involved?  I haven't learned anything about it in class or in my textbooks. edit: My homework program also says that your answer is incorrect.

Comment: You are welcome. I edited my answer, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, this is great.  I didn't notice that you changed 981 to 985.

Comment: Wait, the 985 was a mistake! The 981 is the correct!

Comment: Hey, this is a great explanation.  I was just able to do another one of these by hand.

Comment: Wow thank you, great to hear that :)!!! Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint1**:
$$\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{981}{n+5}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{i^2}{n^2} \right)
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{981}{n+5} \cdot \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2}{n^2}\\
\end{split}$$

**Hint2**:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 = \frac{n\cdot (n+1) \cdot 2n+1)}{6}$$

---

$$\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{981}{n+5}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{i^2}{n^2} \right)
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{981}{n+5} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2}{n^2}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{981}{n+5} \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6 \cdot n^2}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n} \cdot \frac{981 (2n^2+3n+1)}{(6n^2 +30n)}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2} \cdot \frac{981\cdot(2+\frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2})}{6(1 + \frac{30}{n})} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{327\cdot(2+\frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2})}{2(1 + \frac{30}{n})}  &= 327
\end{split}$$

Comment: What do I do with the limit?  The limit is 0, right?

Comment: No, 327 as I wrote. Limit of denominator is $2$ and nominator $327 \cdot 2$.

Look, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{n} = 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = 0$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2 + \frac{3}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right) = 2$. And so on.

Comment: Where does the following come from: $$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{6} $$

Comment: That's the summation formula for i^2.

Comment: @bd1251252: It's [well known fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number#Formula). Exists so many derivations of this formula. You can find some in Internet, I believe, here too. An interesting way is to note the obvious fact $$ (a_2 - a_1) + (a_3 - a_2) + \dots + (a_{n+1} - a_{n}) = a_{n+1}-a_1$$

And let $ a_i = \frac{(2i - 1)^3}{24}$.

I left you rest. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Pull the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ out of the sum and use the identity $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

I see a (calculus) tag.  So ... that homework problem must follow a chapter on Riemann sums ...  Let's try that.

Consider the integral
$$
\int_0^1 x^2\,dx = \frac{1}{3} .
$$
That integrand $x^2$ is continuous, therefore Riemann integrable.  Consider the "upper sums" for $n$ equal-size intervals.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{n} \to \frac{1}{3}
$$
as $n \to \infty$.  So the original probem must have answer $981/3 = 327$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With *Stolz-Ces$\grave{a}$ro Theorem*:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}{981 \over n + 5}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\pars{i^{2} \over n^{2}}} & =
981\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 6}\pars{n + 1}^{2} - \pars{n + 5}n^{2}}
\pars{\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1}i^{2} - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}i^{2}}
\\[3mm] &=
981\lim_{n \to \infty}{n^{2} + 2n + 1 \over 3n^{2} + 13n + 6} =
327\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 + 2/n + 1/n^{2} \over 1 + 13/\pars{3n} + 2/n^{2}} =
\color{#f00}{327}
\end{align}